Edit page displays 'critical error has occurred' but when debugging is turned on, there are no error messages
I was encountering a 'there has been a critical error' message when trying to edit pages/posts on a WP site. I enabled debugging and fixed the problems that were being displayed.
I thought I'd got them all but when I turned debugging off again, I was still getting the critical error message. Turned debugging back on again and the page displayed fine but there were no error messages displayed.
So for now, I have to leave debugging turned on to be able to edit pages.
Any ideas why that might be?
